# How to make friends with NumberFormatter and Optional from SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

`NumberFormatter` works fine with `Int`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var value: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test FieldNumberView")
            FieldNumberView(
                title: "Number",
                value: self.$value,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 999
            )
        }
    }
}
struct FieldNumberView : View {
    @Binding private var value: Int
    private let title: String
    private let formatterNumber: NumberFormatter
    init(title: String = "", value: Binding<Int>, minValue: Int? = nil, maxValue: Int? = nil) {
        self._value = value
        self.title = title
        self.formatterNumber = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.minimum = minValue.map { .init(value: $0) }
            formatter.maximum = maxValue.map { .init(value: $0) }
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            self.title,
            value: self._value,
            formatter: self.formatterNumber
        )
    }
}
```

`NumberFormatter` doesn't want to work with `Int?`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var value: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test FieldNumberView")
            FieldNumberView(
                title: "Number",
                value: self.$value,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 999
            )
        }
    }
}
struct FieldNumberView : View {
    @Binding private var value: Int?
    private let title: String
    private let formatterNumber: NumberFormatter
    init(title: String = "", value: Binding<Int?>, minValue: Int? = nil, maxValue: Int? = nil) {
        self._value = value
        self.title = title
        self.formatterNumber = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.minimum = minValue.map { .init(value: $0) }
            formatter.maximum = maxValue.map { .init(value: $0) }
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            self.title,
            value: self._value,
            formatter: self.formatterNumber
        )
    }
}
```

Perhaps you can somehow define the `NumberFormatter` to work with `Optional`, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post what you were trying to do, and why you are using the optional? It is fine to post code that doesn't quite work.

Comment: @Yrb, Thanks for the comment. I added a non-working code. I need the ability to enter a value in the field with some restriction with the ability to delete it completely. That is, this field is optional according to business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a better solution than using `UITextField`.
Here is the code:

```
struct CustomNumberField : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding private var value: Int?
    private let minValue: Int?
    private let maxValue: Int?
    private let font: UIFont?
    private let textColor: UIColor?
    
    init(value: Binding<Int?>, minValue: Int? = nil, maxValue: Int? = nil, font: UIFont? = nil, textColor: UIColor? = nil) {
        self._value = value
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
        self.font = font
        self.textColor = textColor
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.font = self.font
        textField.textColor = self.textColor
        // MARK: Add Buttons
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let clearButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: .done, target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.clearButtonTapped(button:)))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
        toolBar.setItems([clearButton, spacer, doneButton], animated: true)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        // MARK: Save TextField
        context.coordinator.textField = textField
        // MARK: Force Update
        self.updateUIView(textField, context: context)
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = self.value.map { String($0) } ?? ""
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        public var textField: UITextField? = nil
        
        private let parent: CustomNumberField
        
        init(_ parent: CustomNumberField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func clearButtonTapped(button: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
            self.textField?.text = nil
        }
        
        @objc func doneButtonTapped(button: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
            self.textField?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            guard let rawText = textField.text else {
                return true
            }
            let newText = NSString(string: rawText).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            if newText.isEmpty {
                return true
            }
            guard let newValue = Int(newText) else {
                return false
            }
            if let minValue = self.parent.minValue {
                if newValue < minValue {
                    return false
                }
            }
            if let maxValue = self.parent.maxValue {
                if newValue > maxValue {
                    return false
                }
            }
            guard String(newValue) == newText else {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.parent.value = {
                if let text = textField.text, text.isEmpty == false {
                    return Int(text)
                }
                return nil
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. Perhaps there is a better option, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0**

You could use the newer initializer for `TextField` that uses `FormatStyle` which also works with Optionals.

```
TextField("", value: $value, format: .number, prompt: Text("..."))
```

You can refine your desired Format with a custom `FormatStyle`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is you can't. They will not be friends, so use a custom Binding to come between them and provide your `FieldNumberView` with a non-optional.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var value: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test FieldNumberView")
            Text("value = \(value?.description ?? "nil")")
            FieldNumberView(
                title: "Number",
                // Custom Binding here
                value: Binding<Int>(
                    get: { value ?? 0 },
                    set: { newValue in
                        value = newValue
                    }
                ),
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 999
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The caveat with this approach is that if the user changes the field, `value` in `ContentView()` becomes non-nil. I am not entirely sure of the underlying need for the nil value, but you can either disable the view from entry, remove it completely, etc., based on your needs.

Comment: In your case, it will be impossible to distinguish the values: `nil` and `0`. And I need the screen not to display the value when `nil`. It is also important to be able to set `nil`. I used this solution: https://gist.github.com/darrarski/065520cc7095a7e0e33e72373feab3ac. I don't know how good it is, but it works. p.s. I didn't rate you for the answer.